# how to make JQuery 1.8.3 compatible with other jquery libraries

Tags: jquery, conflict

I have this code to adjust an image's position

```
$(window).load(function() {
    center();

});


$(window).resize(function() {
        center();

});

function center() {
        var pos =  $('#banner img').width() - $(window).width();
        $('#banner img').css({
            left : pos / 2 * -1
        });
}
```

I know that using jQuery(function($) so it won't be in conflict with other $(document).ready in other jquery libraries. How write it so $(window).load & resize won't be in conflict? and the limit is version 1.8.3 too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it... Binding the event seems too work.

```
jQuery(window).on("load resize",function(e){
            center();
});

function center() {
        var pos =  jQuery('#banner img').width() - jQuery(window).width();
        jQuery('#banner img').css({
            left : pos / 2 * -1
        });


}
```